# Drupal Core Poll - http 403 error

Tags: drupal

I've asked this before but with other questions so I posted it again. I'm actually receiving an error message

> An HTTP error 403 occurred.  /poll/js

when trying to add additional option in poll. I'm using the Drupal Core Poll and the latest version of files. I have several modules including boost which is known to have issues on Poll. I disabled the Boost module but it did solve the issue. I just hope that anyone could help me. I'm just new to Drupal and still studying. I would like this issue to be fixed on our Prod site. Thank you thank you so much!

Comment: What do you see when you visit example.com/poll/js in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 403 is access denied. So this means that with your current user you don't have rights to access to the path. Check the user permissions for the Pool module.

Comment: Hi! Bladedu. I already checked the permission and all is enabled for authentic users. I'm using the admin account also. Any other idea?